# SQL - searching 2 tables and returning results from one

Tags: sql

I currently have 2 tables for tickets. Table 1 is tickets and table 2 is repsonses.

I currently do

```
select id, subject, description 
from tickets 
where subject like '%hello%';
```

This works but I also want to return the same fields but where hello matches the message field in the responses table.

E.g. I was hoping I could do:

```
select id, subject, description 
from tickets, responses 
where tickets.subject like '%hello%' OR responses.message like '%hello%';
```

ticketid in the responses table is the same as id in the tickets table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will always be a responses record:

```
  select tickets.id, tickets.subject, tickets.description 
  from tickets, responses 
  where
    tickets.id = responses.id and
    ( tickets.subject like '%hello%' or 
      responses.message like '%hello%' )
```

If tickets can exist without responses:

```
  select tickets.id, tickets.subject, tickets.description 
  from tickets left outer join responses on tickets.id = responses.id
  where
    tickets.subject like '%hello%' or 
    responses.message like '%hello%'
```

Comment: Yes this works great thanks! I was missing the brackets so evidently they made all the difference!

Comment: He can't; he doesn't have reputation. He can accept your response as correct, however.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you only want the results from the tickets table?  You could use `tableName.*` or use the tableName.columnName to get just the results from that original table.

```
select tickets.id, tickets.subject, tickets.description 
from tickets, responses 
where tickets.id = responses.id
AND (tickets.subject like '%hello%' 
OR responses.message like '%hello%')
```

Comment: Hi yes you understand right and the above is what I tried but it just hanged (also i put in ands etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need left join -

```
select id, subject, description 
from tickets left join responses on tickets.id = responses.ticketid
where tickets.subject like '%hello%' OR responses.message like '%hello%';
```

[Correction] LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables:

```
SELECT `tickets`.`id`, `tickets`.`subject`, `tickets`.`description`, `responses`.`message` 
LEFT JOIN `responses` ON `tickets`.`id` = `responses`.`id` 
WHERE `tickets`.`subject` like '%hello%' OR responses.message like '%hello%'
```